# Counting pagination elements and add CSS to it

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, counting

So I found a nice PHP pagination class and adapted it for my needs.

```
/*********************************************\
* Mini Paginator                              *
* Made by Wilson Fernandez for multicoders.com*
* wilsonimport@gmail.com                      *
\*********************************************/
```

Now I want to make it responsive and found a cool way to do this here -> [Responsive pagination with Kaminari](http://www.ripariandata.com/blog/responsive-pagination-with-kaminari).
After several tries I noticed, that adding classes to the pagination elements is not as trivial as it first looks (at least for me). I tried to do it in PHP and I looked for a solution with jQuery, but with no luck.
So I hope for some help here. :)

The original pagination output is this:

```
<div id = "container">
    <div class = "pagination">
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=5"> Vorherige </a>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=1">1</a>
        <span class = "dots">...</span>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=3">3</a>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=4">4</a>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=5">5</a>
        <div class = "page active">6</div>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=7">7</a>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=8">8</a>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=9">9</a>
        <span class = "dots">...</span>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=214">214</a>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=7"> Nächste </a>
        <form id = "paginationForm" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "" method = "get" name = "availPages">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I need classes added like that (note the "away-n" classes:

```
<div id = "container">
    <div class = "pagination">
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=5"> Vorherige </a>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=1">1</a>
        <span class = "dots">...</span>
        <a class = "page away-3" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=3">3</a>
        <a class = "page away-2" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=4">4</a>
        <a class = "page away-1" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=5">5</a>
        <div class = "page active away-0">6</div>
        <a class = "page away-1" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=7">7</a>
        <a class = "page away-2" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=8">8</a>
        <a class = "page away-3" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=9">9</a>
        <span class = "dots">...</span>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=214">214</a>
        <a class = "page" href = "/development/paginator/index.php?current_page=7"> Nächste </a>
        <form id = "paginationForm" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "" method = "get" name = "availPages">
    </div>
</div>
```

In short, from the current page class (active) there should be added a "counting class" to the left (up) and to the right (down) till class "dots" or, if no dots, to the last element (but not the next and previous, the very last elements).

My question: How could this be done?
Solution preferred with PHP, but easier I guess with jQuery.
Suggestions, please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have done with your Query and CSS in your pagination layout.
This is simple php code that's you can experiments with the variables inside.

just run with new php file and you can learn it.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .pagination {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .pagination *{
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #cecece;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .active{
        background: #dedede;
    }
</style>
<?php

$count_sides_numb = 3;  // count of navigation numbers can you show in beside active page number, you can edit this.
$active_page = (!empty($_GET['current_page']) ? $_GET['current_page']:5);

$count_records = 10000; // total your records database
$recs_in_page = 25;     // total records per page
$count_pages = round($count_records/$recs_in_page,0);

$before_side_numb = $active_page-$count_sides_numb-1;
$after_side_numb = $active_page+$count_sides_numb+1;

// cek for using dot navigation.
$use_dot_btn = true;
if($after_side_numb >= $count_pages ||
    $before_side_numb <= 1) $use_dot_btn = false;

echo "<div id = \"container\">
    <div class = \"pagination\" style=\"display:inline-block;\">";

        echo ($active_page > 1 ? "<a class = \"page\" href = \"/index.php?current_page=".($active_page-1)."\">Vorherige</a>":"<div class=\"page\">Vorherige</div>");
        echo ($before_side_numb+1 > 1 ? "<a class = \"page\" href = \"/index.php?current_page=1\">1</a>":"");
        echo ($use_dot_btn ? "<span class = \"dots\">...</span>":"");

        $first = $before_side_numb+1 < 1 ? 1:$before_side_numb+1;
        for($i=$first; $i<$active_page;$i++){
            echo "<a class = \"page away-$count_sides_numb\" href = \"/index.php?current_page=$i\">$i</a>";
            $count_sides_numb -=1;
        }
        echo "<div class = \"page active away-0\">$active_page</div>";

        $last = $after_side_numb-1 > $count_pages ? $count_pages:$after_side_numb-1;
        for($i=$active_page+1; $i<=$last;$i++){
            echo "<a class = \"page away-$count_sides_numb\" href = \"/index.php?current_page=$i\">$i</a>";
            $count_sides_numb +=1;
        }

        echo ($use_dot_btn ? "<span class = \"dots\">...</span>":"");
        echo $after_side_numb-1 < $count_pages ? "<a class = \"page\" href = \"/index.php?current_page=$count_pages\">$count_pages</a>":"";
        echo $active_page < $count_pages ? "<a class = \"page\" href = \"/index.php?current_page=".($active_page+1)."\">Nächste</a>":"<div class=\"page\">Nächste</div>";

    echo "</div>
</div>";
?>
```

*note: fix and adjust url navigations.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need/want to implement this "feature" into the existing php class I mentioned. So, building the pagination "from scratch" is not my goal.

The class is found here -> http://multicoders.com/sdm_downloads/mini-paginator/

Comment: the algorithm of your class is almost the same with above code, you can implement to your class. just the learn and it's not difficult.

Comment: Did you actually looked into the class file from the link I provided?

Comment: yes, i was learn that's class (in mini_paginator1.rar) and there's almost the same workflow.

Comment: OK, let me check this later on and I will then response again.

Comment: Allright, I checked the code and it is useable.
I had to tweak it a bit but now it does exactly what it should. Many thanks.